# In Tableau, I'm looking to sort by median value in a table with a hierarchy

Tags: tableau-api, aggregation

The nature of the data is proprietary, but [here's a sketch of what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbYUf.jpg).

We have companies that contain products.  Each product has sales values from 2017 and 2018.  For each Company/Product combination, I want the median sales for that year.  Then I want to sort descendingly by median 2017 sales.

I've tried making a hierarchy of Company -> Product and sorting Product by median 2017 sales, where median 2017 sales is the sales field set to NULL if the sale was made in 2018.  But this doesn't actually put the bars in descending order.

Comment: can you attach the report with dummy data.. or atleast add dummy data to your question? It is difficult to understand by just seeing the hand drawn sketch

Answer (score 0):

Talking from reference of Tableau 10.4, you can sort by both company and product separately if you like. 
Considering you want to sort by median 2017 sales, create a calculated field with condition if year=2017 then sales and then calculate median to break down the problem.

Alternatively and depending on the format of your underlying data, you can use level of detail calculation where you fix the year and calculate median as available in an example here: https://community.tableau.com/thread/178724

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is make a nested sort -- Within each company, sort the products associated with that company. If you just blindly sort the companies and products separately, then if two companies offer the same product, then the sort order will not be what you intend. You will assign an order to all products irrespective of company.

Tableau demonstrated a coming feature to make this common use case very easy at the 2017 Tableau Conference, but it isn't too difficult with the current version.

1. Select your two discrete fields in the data pane, company and product, in your case, and then Create Combined Field.
2. Place the combined field on the Row or Column shelf between the two original fields.
3. Apply the desired sort to the combined field
4. Hide the header for the combined field - i.e. right click on the field on the Row or Column shelf to find that option